# MATLAB: Replace a row/column in a cell array with NaN

Tags: matlab, nan, cell-array

How am I supposed to replace a complete row/column within a cell array with NaNs?

```
test = cell(3,2);

% These calls won't do it
test{2,:} = nan;
test(2,:) = nan;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test(2,:) = repmat({nan},1,2);
```

Comment: also if it is just the same value `test1(2,:) = {nan};`